# Relacionar valores de una lista con cadenas escritas por el usuario

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estoy intentando relacionar valores de una lista con cadenas escritas por el usuario como en este ejemplo:
Queremos que las cadenas escritas por el usuario se relacionen con otras que tenemos nosotros: trabajo casa y familia. queremos dividir la cadena en valores separados e imprirmir por pantalla el resultado.

por ejemplo:

EL usuario escribe oficina barrio fernandez

y el resultado deberia ser:

```
trabajo: oficina
casa: barrio
familia: fernandez.
```

Lo que tengo de momento es esto:

```
consulta = str(input('Introduzca situacion laboral:'))

SL = ['trabajo', 'oficina', 'familia']

print ('La situacion laboral es: ')
print(SL[0], consulta[0])
print(SL[1],consulta[1])
print(SL[2], consulta [2])
```

pero lo que me devuelve es:

```
trabajo: o
casa: f
familia: i
```

Entiendo que esta  cogiendo solo 'oficina' como valor a relacionar pero no entiendo por qué.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que te limitas a acceder a los caracteres de la cadena por índice cuando lo que, en principio, quieres es iterar sobre las palabras.

Lo mas simple es usar el método de las cadenas [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) y dividir la cadena en una lista de subcadenas usando los espacios como separador. Recibe dos argumentos, el primero es una cadena que es el separador a usar y el segundo argumento es entero que representa el número máximo de particiones que queremos:

```
consulta = input('Introduzca situacion laboral:')

consulta  = consulta.split()

SL = ['trabajo', 'oficina', 'familia']

print ('La situacion laboral es: ')
print(SL[0], consulta[0])
print(SL[1],consulta[1])
print(SL[2], consulta [2])
```

**Salida:**

```
>>> Introduzca situacion laboral:oficina barrio fernandez
La situacion laboral es: 
trabajo oficina
oficina barrio
familia fernandez
```

Si vas a querer capturar frases vas a necesitar especificar un delimitador diferente. Por otro lado, esto asume que la entrada es válida siempre, que tiene siempre tres palabras. Si esto no ocurre recibirás una excepción por intentar acceder a un índice inexistente. Puedes resolver esto comprobando la longitud de tu lista retornada por `split` (pidiendo de nuevo la cadena o lanzando una excepción):

```
sl = ['Trabajo', 'Oficina', 'Familia']

while True:
    consulta = input('Introduzca situación laboral: ')
    consulta = [sc.strip() for sc in consulta.split(",") if sc.strip()]
    if len(consulta) == len(sl):
        break
    print("Error: Formato de entrada incorrecta.")

print ('La situacion laboral es: ')
print(*("{}: {}.".format(s,  c) for s,  c in zip(sl,  consulta)),  sep = "\n")
```

Para parsear string más complejos es posible que sea mucho más simple usar [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) y usar expresiones regulares para determinar el patrón:

```
import re

sl = ['trabajo', 'oficina', 'familia']
patt = re.compile("^\s+|\s*,\s*|\s+$")    
while True:
    consulta = input('Introduzca situación laboral("Trabajo, Oficina, Familia"): ')
    consulta = [sc for sc in re.split(patt,  consulta) if sc]
    if len(consulta) == len(sl):
        break
    print("Error: Formato de entrada incorrecta.")

print ('La situacion laboral es: ')
print(*("{}: {}.".format(s,  c) for s,  c in zip(sl,  consulta)),  sep = "\n")
```

Para ambos ejemplos la salida es idéntica, se usa la coma ("`,`") como separador de cada item y se eliminan todos los espacios que pueda haber al principio o al final de cada item:

```
>>> Introduzca situación laboral: Contable, Barrio La Paz,
Error: Formato de entrada incorrecta.
Introduzca situación laboral: Contable, Barrio La Paz, Fernádez García
La situacion laboral es: 
Trabajo: Contable.
Oficina: Barrio La Paz.
Familia: Fernádez García.
```

Se usa [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) y un ciclo `for` para imprimir. `zip` simplemente coge dos iterables con los mismos items y crea un iterable con tuplas agrupando los elemnetos con el mismo índice de cada iterable.

> **Nota:** no es necesario el casteo a `str` de la salida de `input`, en Python 3 `input` retorna una cadena siempre.